# WSS 3.0, Insert Into .. Select created/modded by columns

Tags: sql, sharepoint, ms-access, wss

I've just built a query in Access 2007 that needs to move some items from ListA to ListB and retain the created by and modified by columns. The query works and looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [ListA] ( [Column1], [Modified By], [Created By] )
SELECT [Column1], [Modified By], [Created By] 
FROM [ListB];
```

The problem is the Created By and Modified By fields are updated on the new list to reflect the user that actually executes the query through Access.

Is there any way around this or is it just a limitation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible from Access or any other end user accessible location.  Where this is possible from is the client object model through the SystemUpdate method. http://programming.cmsstores.com/microsoft-sharepoint-systemupdate-and-update-using-object-model/